# Minimal sufficient statistic implies any complete statistic is also minimal sufficient

Tags: statistics, reference-request, statistical-inference

I am reading about data reduction of Casella book. There is a theorem establishing the next:

If a minimal sufficient statistic exists, then any complete statistic is also a minimal sufficient statistic.

A proof is no provided by the author; is there a reference for a formal proof of this fact?

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

Comment: For a simple argument you can see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/435938/relationship-between-completeness-and-sufficiency/.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is called **Bahadur's theorem**.

A version of it is [proved here](https://www.math.kth.se/matstat/gru/Statistical%20inference/Lecture5.pdf) as Theorem 12.

I could not find a version where sufficiency of the statistic is not a requirement from the premise.

Comment: Thanks for the help.